# WHERE clause in LINQ statement that pulls specific match or everything if no match found

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to write a LINQ statement that will pull all the items from a table where the column Type matches what the user selects in a dropdown menu but if no matches are found then it returns ALL the items from the table regardless of the Type. I have  gotten it to return all the items that match the user’s selection but I cannot figure out what code needs to be added so that if no matches are found it defaults to pulling all the items in the table.

Current Code:

```
(from i in db.ItemTypeTranslations
    join st in db.SectionTranslations
    on i.ItemType.SectionID equals st.SectionID
    where i.CultureID == 1 && i.ItemType.SectionID == SelectedSection
    select new
    {
       st.SectionID,
       st.Title,
       i.ItemTypeName
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator to turn your where clause into a conditional and have your current select as the successful branch and the select that returns everything as the unsuccessful branch.

Similar question asked on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/c039f631-a503-427f-84e4-d6e3637e4bf8/)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
where i.CultureID == 1 && (i.ItemType.SectionID == SelectedSection || String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedSection))
```

I am assuming that SelectedSection is a string. If not, the principle will be the same: Where (SectionID == SelectedSection OR SelectedSection == some-default-value)

Edit: I just re-read your question, and realized that I'm answering the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Maggy May. That helped me a lot I ended up with this code that looks to be working:

```
(from i in db.ItemTypeTranslations
                                          join st in db.SectionTranslations
                                          on i.ItemType.SectionID equals st.SectionID
                                          where (SelectedSection == 0 ? true : i.ItemType.SectionID == SelectedSection) && i.CultureID == 1
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              i.ItemTypeID,
                                              st.Title,
                                              i.ItemTypeName
                                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: The orginal code I posted here was not working but with a slight tweek it is working now. I updated the code block with the confirmed working code.